Key Error when having spaces and "\n" in multiline f-string
Trying to format SPARQL queries in python using f-strings in order to build different queries from a template,
but i'm getting KeyError when i try to format a multiline string:
query = f'''SELECT ?age
WHERE {{
  wd:{0} wdt:{1} ?birthdate.
  BIND(now() - ?birthdate AS ?age)
}}'''

print(query.format('Q84','P1082'))

KeyError: '\n           wd'

Any idea helps, i'd prefer not to split the queries line by line.

Don't use an f-string. Just: query = '''SELECT ?age ... 

@quamrana same error if i try to format the parameters with no f string, only thing that works is line by line.

You need to double all the braces; first the f-string reduces {{ to {, then the format method reduces any remaining {{ to {.

And that's the problem, isn't it?  The f string converts the double-braces to single braces, and the format call tries to interpret the single braces.  So, remove the leading f and it should work.

@m.rp I think you might have misunderstood what quamrama is saying: If you remove the f prefix from the string (nothing more than that), then this code works perfectly. What the f-string is doing here is inserting the integers 0 and 1, not creating replacement fields for use by str.format().

typo definetily, what @quamrana is right. Thanks guys, last time i used this stuff was like 5 years ago...

You need to double all your braces. Both the f-string and the format method called on the resulting string will reduce {{ and }} to { and }, respectively. So for each literal { you want in the result, you need four {.
Really, query does not contain a query, but a query template.
>>> query = f'''SELECT ?age
... WHERE {{{{
... wd:{{0}} wdt:{{1}} ?birthdate.
... BIND(now() - ?birthdate AS ?age)
... }}}}'''
>>> print(query)
SELECT ?age
WHERE {{
wd:{0} wdt:{1} ?birthdate.
BIND(now() - ?birthdate AS ?age)
}}
>>> print(query.format('Q84', 'P'))
SELECT ?age
WHERE {
wd:Q84 wdt:P ?birthdate.
BIND(now() - ?birthdate AS ?age)
}

(I assume you are aware of the dangers of creating parameterized queries via string interpolation, and have taken the necessary precautions to sanitize the inputs to query.format.)
The simplest thing to do, though, is to use an f-string or the format method, rather than both. You don't need two rounds of substitution.

Then the f-string does nothing. It's better to just remove the f, as quamrama commented.

I though it was worth spelling out why the f-string contributed to the problem.

If there was another level of interpolation, absolutely, but it seems like OP just made a typo (or other mistake).

definitely a typo, f-string or not that works thanks
